# How to manipulate this column of less than/greater than?

Tags: dataset, feature-selection, data-cleaning, feature-extraction, excel

I have a dataset in which one column is as given in the picture. 
What will be the best way to handle such a column?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a categorical variable. There are multiple ways to handle categorical variables in the literature -

**Dummification (mostly for nominal variables)**

The variable is split and converted into multiple binary variables (the number of variables should be `1-(number of classes)` ).

Python example -

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', 
                    '>50k', '>50k', '>50k', '>50k', '>50k', '<=50k'])

print(pd.get_dummies(series).iloc[:, 1:])
```

**Output**

```
>50k
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
7      1
8      1
9      1
10     1
11     1
12     0
```

Notice how the information that was string has been now *encoded* in numbers. The reason was dropping a column is so that there is no perfect multicollinearity.

**Ranking(in case of ordinal variables)**

These are the cases where you can clearly `rank` the variables. In your case it would make more sense to rank them as we know then `>50k` is actually more than `<50k`.

Use the ranking method in you salary case and the dummification method for nominal cases (like `location` variables - where it can't be ordered)

Python example -

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', '<=50k', 
                    '>50k', '>50k', '>50k', '>50k', '>50k', '<=50k'])
uniq = series.unique()
ranks = { uniq[i]:i+1 for i in range(len(uniq)) }
print(ranks)
series_ranked = series.apply(lambda x: ranks[x])
print(series_ranked)
```

**Output**

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    2
12    1
dtype: int64
```

Again, in no way is this an exhaustive answer, but rest assured these are the most popular methods used to deal with categorical variables. Hope that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am new to this and more familiar with R. It will take some time understand this.